# Calculating UV radiation dose in a moving airstream

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, integration

I am trying to calculate the UVC irradiation dose absorbed by an airstream passing around a set of multiple (3) UVC lightbulbs.

Here is a brief description of the scenario:

> $3000$ CFM of $55F$ air is passing through a $24" ×  \ 24"$ , $24"$ long device with three UVC bulbs installed in a cross flow orientation (equally spaced installation at $4"$ , $12"$ , $20"$ heights). The air is traveling approximately $750 \ \mathrm{ft/min}$. The bulbs are rated for $36 \ W$ total and $11$.$2 \ \mathrm{W}$ UVC radiation at $100 \ \mathrm{hr}$. Bulb length is $415 \ \mathrm{mm}$.

If the distance from the lamp is assumed to be $4"$, I can use the following equations to calculate the irradiance:

$$E=\frac{\phi}{(2\pi^2ld)} (2\alpha+\sin(2\alpha))$$

Where ;

$\alpha = \arctan \frac{L}{2D}$, in radians , i.e

$\alpha = \mathrm{arctan \frac{0.415 \ m}{2×0.1016 \ m} = 1.115 \ rad}$.

Using the irradiance formula, I calculate total irradiance $E=5108 \ \mathrm{µW/cm}^2$. (Multiplying a single bulb irradiance by 3, since there are three bulbs.)

Going back to $750 \ \mathrm{fpm}$ air velocity in the device, it takes $0.16 \ s$ for the air to pass through the $24"$ device. Using the formula to calculate UV dose,

$D_{UV}=It$

$D_{UV}=\frac{817.22 \ \mathrm{µW} × s}{cm^2}$

Here is where I run into a fundamental question that I have not had been able to find an answer for. Are those formulas assuming an exposure distance of $0.1016m$  from the lamp for the entire $0.16s$ ? Obviously, the airstream will begin receiving UV dose as soon as it enters the device, albeit at a much lower level, with intensity peaking for the split second the air passes directly adjacent to the UVC bulbs.

Are there any differential equations or integrals that can be established to sum the total UV dosage received by a particle across the entire device length? Would the radiation at the boundaries be so insignificant that it can be ignored?
Additionally, I have ignored factors such as reflectivity, view factor, and wind chill as I have not been able to work them into my formulas yet. Any guidance on this would be appreciated!

I appreciate any assistance on this problem!
I am new to this site so forgive me if I posted anything incorrectly.
Thank you

Comment: If you surround the lamp with mirror surfaces, how many passes through the airstream are expected before the light is attenuated or lost to reflection inefficiency?

Comment: @Whit3rd Would knowing that make a difference in the result? This device is made of aluminum, probably should have included that for reflectivity purposes.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for the input, it is updated.

Comment: @rreng If the entire region is flooded with UV and reflected UV light, it's as if  many mirror-images of the sources are extra sources.   Assuming dilute (dust?) particles stop the UV, as well as reflection inefficiency (maybe 80%?), those 11W sources and all their (distorted) mirror-images form an infinite array of bright virtual images, dimming with distance... and distance to the single closest (real) source isn't necessarily dominant.  One could also, though, consider average energy density based on decay TIME of the UV, and UV power, and volume.

Comment: @Whit3rd I appreciate your willingness to help me understand this topic more thoroughly. The average reflectance I have found through research for untreated aluminum is 40-60%. If we assume an average 50% reflectivity, how would that work into the equations to get a better estimate for the UV dose received by a particle passing through the device. Also, does the Keitz equation (centered in original question) work for a moving reference point as set up in the hypothetical example? Is it possible/necessary to set up a time or distance based integral to get a total dose?